# How relevant is quasiparticle tunneling noise to the T1 of a transmon?

Tags: noise, transmon

I wish to check how much quasiparticle noise contributes to the relaxation of a transmon qubit since I need to use it for a project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.